# How to know when a Gdk.Pixbuf is finished loading

Tags: gtk2, gdk, pixbuf

I am loading a Gdk.Pixbuf from bytes:

```
_pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(bytes);
```

Then, I'd like to read the _pixbuf data. But, it appears that the data is actually loading in the background because the data doesn't exist for a while. If I wait, all is fine.

How can I either know when it is finished, or force the update?

Comment: What language are you using ? Also I think you want Pixbuf.from_data or Pixbuf.with_unowned_data instead of the constructor you specify

Comment: I'm using C#, and the code I have works fine. It's just that when I try to do something with the data, it may not be fully loaded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this code was fine... I was executing it in the graphics thread, and returning before it was done. Once I executed it so that it blocked until it was complete, then all was fine.